# Assembly 'XYZ' with identity 'XYZ' uses 'System.Runtime' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime'

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-standard-2.1

> Assembly 'XYZ' with identity 'XYZ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Getting above error in Project PQR which .Net Standard 2.1
XYZ is dotnet Core 3.1 Library which is referenced PQR.

Can't we reference dotnet 3.1 in .Net Standard 2.1 library?

Comment: Not without adding framework referenced at which point you're not really dotnet standard anymore

Comment: only other way. you can only reference .net standard lib in a .net core 3.1 app.

Comment: I converted dotnet core 3.1 to Standard 2.1 to resolve this issue. for converting 3.1 to standard 2.1 replace <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> to <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework> in .csproj

Comment: this is the correct way. nice to hear that it works